# Verilog Signed Addition Subtraction error

Tags: verilog, addition, signed

I've been working on a Verilog program that is supposed to add a signed 8-bit input to the 16-bit output on every clock increment and reset on receiving a reset signal. The addition portion is working fine, and even adding the negative 1 value works, but I'm getting strange results in the simulation for numbers less than that. It's been about a year since I last used Verilog, and despite trying everything I can think of, I'm uncertain what the problem is. Here's what I have as far as code:

```
module varcount (clk, reset, in, out);
input clk, reset;
input [7:0] in;
output reg [15:0] out;
reg [15:0] temp;
reg [15:0]count;
parameter X=1000000;
always @ (posedge clk)
   begin
    if (in[7] == 1)
    begin
    temp = 16'b00000000000000001 + !in;
    count = count - temp;
    if (reset)
    begin
        count = 0;
        out = 0;
    end
    out = count;
end
    else
    begin
        count = count + in;
        if (reset)
        begin
            count = 0;
            out = 0;
        end
        out = count;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Here's my simulation input:

[image]

And here's the output that I get.

[image]

It seems like a straight-forward error in my program, but I can't identify it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's hard to read your code because you have not indented it properly. You also do not show what you expect to be the correct result versus the actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are doing a logical negation of `in` versus a bitwise negation.

Your code could be greatly simplified by

- moving the `reset` conditional branch to the top level
- using `signed` data types
- using Verilog-2001 style port declarations

For example:

```
module varcount (input clk, reset, 
          wire signed [7:0] in, 
   output reg signed [15:0] out);
 always @ (posedge clk)
            if (reset)
              out = 0;
            else
              out = out + in;
endmodule
```

Comment: Is there any way to get from an unsigned array to a signed array and vise-versa?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question, with a new example.

Answer (score 0):

I see this in your code:

```
temp = 16'b00000000000000001 + !in;
count = count - temp;
```

temp looks like your trying to calculate a twos complement. `!` is a logical NOT. you would want `~` for a bit wise invert.

so you could have:

```
sum  <= a + (~b +1'b1);
```

Or

```
sum <= a - b;
```

ie `-b` == `(~b +1'b1)`